# Apache: see which page/virtual host is killing my server

Tags: apache-2.2

I'm unable to bring my web server back online. The server just keeps trashing and I'm forced to powercycle it to reboot.

I'm on a shared host, so it's even harder to find the culprit.

How can I find which specific page (or, at least, which virtual host) is going berserk with CPU usage?

I'm on CentOS with a fairly standard Apahce+MySQL+PHP.

Thanks!

Comment: Being on a shared host but having the ability to reboot it is an unusual combination.  How have you determined that Apache is the culprit?  Do you have any performance graphing using something like Cacti, Zabbix, Munin, etc?

Answer (score 2):

Probably the best idea is to install apachetop. https://code.google.com/p/apachetop/, you can also use Apache's server-status, but apachetop will make it alot more readable.

Answer (score 0):

A page has really nothing to do with this problem.

The following command should output a list of pids for httpd sorted by CPU percentage with the current working directory that httpd worker is in.

This of course assumes that httpd is the culprit.

```
IFS=" "; ps -A ho pcpu,comm,pid | grep httpd | sort -k1n \
while read pcpu comm pid; do \
    echo -n "${pcpu"}: "l pwdx "${pid}"; 
done
```

I get output similar to;

```
0.0: 1850: /
0.0: 1852: /
0.0: 1854: /
0.0: 1853: /
0.0: 1855: /
0.0: 1856: /
0.0: 1857: /
0.0: 1858: /
```

This works because apache will change directories into the virtual hosts document root prior to doing any work inside of the virtual host. So whichever virtual host has that document root is the culprit.

If you have more than one virtual host using the same document root you'll need to investigate both vhosts to see what they are up to.

Since I have no apache workers taking up CPU time all of them are 0.0 and thus no ordering is taking place.

If the problem is actually an SQL query dont expect this to show anything.